# Extend Stack Overflow to programming error messages and exceptions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Stack Overflow should add an organizational structure for programming error messages and exceptions.

For example, I was working on MS SQL 2005 server and received the error message

> Operating System error 5(Access is Denied) ...

It would be cool if there was a section in Stack Overflow that would organize this to help me find a solution to my error. I would be able to select "MS SQL 2005," and the site would show a list of error messages related specifically to MS SQL 2005. Then I could pick from the list, or search it for "Operating System error 5(Access is Denied)."

Since Stack Overflow is a question-based site, think of this as asking the question "How can I resolve the MS SQL error message 'Operating System error 5(Access is Denied)'?"

Basically, I want all the Stack Overflow goodness, but organized by product and error message.

I believe there is something to be gained by grouping the error messages. What if the solution is not in Error 5 but in Error 6, which is a similar error?  Grouping would help.

I think this would be especially cool for compiler errors. Wouldn't it be convenient if all the Java `String` errors were in one place, with solutions and suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain how [searching and tags](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmssql%5D+Operating+System+error+5+Access+is+Denied) do not work in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Meta! On this site, you don't need to explicitly say you have a suggestion. Just using the `[feature-request]` tag is enough.

Comment: I don't understand why a solution for error code 5 would ever be posted under the entry for error code 6. If I posted the solution for ORA-00904 under a question about ORA-00933, I'd be downvoted, and rightly so.

Answer (score 7):

You want all the Stack Overflow goodness, without the ability to ask free-form questions; you just want a list of error codes that users can fill in with information. I'm not sure which Stack Exchange features would be particularly useful there; you're basically looking for a wiki

Comment: I agree that its not really a good idea, but the *you're basically looking for a wiki* isn't really that strong of an argument since wiki is in the (not-actually-a) venn diagram

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Yes, SO is partially a wiki -- he wants exactly a wiki. A wiki has 100% of the features he wants, as far as I can tell; he can [go start one](http://www.wikia.com/)